# How can I see the attributes of my smart contract when an "object" is returned?

Tags: solidity, remix

Let's suppose I have a simple smart contract defining a person with a couple of attributes (for instance Name and Age) and in another smart contract I have a population (with an array of people). I could have a function to return one person like:

```
function getPerson(uint _index) view returns(Person){
  return population[_index];
}
```

And I'll get something like: 0x9e0BC6DB02E5aF99b8868f0b732eb45c956B92dD (what is a Person' object). But, I'd like to see the attributes of that person. How can I do that? I could make a function like this one (I guess):

```
function getPersonName(uint _index) view returns(string){
  return population[_index].getName();
}
```

But I don't like this solution. I mean, is there any chance to see the attributes of my Person object having this address 0x9e0BC6DB02E5aF99b8868f0b732eb45c956B92dD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A getter function is the only way to read a variable from another contract. The Solidity compiler automatically creates getter functions for public state variables. So if the `name` variable of the `Person` contract is public you can simply use `population[_index].name()`, no need for a separate `getName()` function.

If you have the address of a smart contract, you can access its functions by casting the address to the smart contract type, for example:

```
Person(0x9e0BC6DB02E5aF99b8868f0b732eb45c956B92dD).getName();
```

or

```
function getPersonName(address _personAddress) view returns(string) {
    return Person(_personAddress).getName();
}
```

I don't have all your code, but you might be overstretching the analogy of smart contracts being like OOP classes. A `struct Person` might be more useful than a `contract Person`.